# Rails store data JSONP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model, jsonp

Say if I did a simple scaffold like rails g scaffold user name:string . 
How would I go through the controller and make the data as jsonp rather than json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 actually allows you to pass a `callback` option to `render` now:

```
def index
  render json: @users.to_json, callback: params[:callback]
end
```

Which would be available at:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users.json?callback=foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: See Ashley Williams Answer!**

JSONP is just wrapping the JSON object in a function call. So something like this

UsersController:

```
def index
  @callback_func_name = params[:callback]
  @users = User.all
end
```

View named `index.js.erb`:

```
<%= @callback_func_name %>(<%= @users.to_json %>)
```

Then the request you issue is:

```
http://localhost.com:3000/users.js?callback=myfunction
```

The details might not be exactly right, but this should get you most of the way there, let me know if you have any questions.